# OEL 6.5 bonding mode=802.3ad no connection

Tags: linux, bonding, lacp, oel

OEL 6.5 bonding mode=802.3ad no connection

I configured 2nic into bond on OEL 6.5. to cisco switch (lacp)

```
----------
|  eth0  |=====+              +~~physical-link~~\
----------    ||  ---------   |                  ----------
              |===| bond0 |==>                   | switch |
----------    ||  ---------   |                  ----------
|  eth2  |=====+              +~~physical-link~~/
----------
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

```
DEVICE=eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
HWADDR=40:f2:e9:26:21:62
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth2

```
DEVICE=eth2
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
HWADDR=40:f2:e9:26:21:64
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0

```
DEVICE=bond0
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=10.0.2.8
NETMASK=255.255.0.0
GATEWAY=10.0.0.1
BONDING_OPTS="mode=802.3ad miimon=100 xmit_hash_policy=layer2+3"
```

ifconfig out:

```
[a1@srv1]# ifconfig bond0
bond0   Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 40:f2:e9:26:1c:fa
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:51651 errors:0 dropped:256 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:269 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:12059710 (11.5 MiB) TX bytes:19006 (18.5 KiB)
```

bond0 out:

```
[a1@srv1]# cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
Ethernet Channel BOnding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic linc aggregation
Transmit Hash Policy: layer2+3 (2)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

802.3ad info
LACP rate: slow
Min links: 0
Aggregator selection policy (ad_select): stable

Active Aggregator Info:
Aggregator ID: 1
Number of ports: 2
Actor Key: 17
Partner Key: 9
Partner Mac Address: 68:ef:bd:08:52:40

Slave Interface: eth0
MII Status: up
Speed: 100 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent WH addr: 40:f2:e9:26:21:62
Aggregator ID: 1
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: eth2
MII Status: up
Speed: 100 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 1
Permanent WH addr: 40:f2:e9:26:21:64
Aggregator ID: 1
Slave queue ID: 0
```

route

```
[a1@srv1]#route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination Gateway     Genmask     Flags   Metric  Ref Use Iface
0.0.0.0     10.0.0.1    0.0.0.0     UG  0   0   0   bond0
10.0.0.0    0.0.0.0.0   255.255.0.0 U   0   0   0   bond0
```

ports config on switch:

```
#show etherchannel load-balance
EtherChannel Load-Balancing Configuration:
src-dst-ip


#sh run
interface Port-channel4
description trunk-to-srv1
switchport
switchport access vlan 123
switchport trunk allowed vlan 123
switchport mode trunk

#show etherchannel summary
Number of channel-groups in use: 10
Number of aggregators:           10

Group  Port-channel  Protocol    Ports
------+-------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------
4      Po4(SU)         LACP      Gi1/25(P)   Gi2/25(P)   Gi5/25(P)
```

then I ping gw and get the answer: Destination Host Unreachable

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Well the LACP all seems fine, the problem is your configured IP Address has not been added to `bond` in your `ifconfig` output.

Answer (score 1):

Like *fukawi2* said, the bond is fine, the IP addressing is the problem.

Do you really have `10.0.0.0/16` configured on your LAN? Is it possibly `10.0.0.0/24` instead? Or some other IP range?

Don't use `ifconfig` and `route`, they are obsolete. Instead use `ip address` and `ip route`.

Comment: In a RHEL/OEL 6.x ecosystem, it's still okay to use the ifconfig command set.

Comment: There are things which `ifconfig` and the older tools cannot do. One good example is additional IP addresses without a `ethX:Y` style subinterface. If you want to use PBR then you must use `ip route`. It's high time to ditch the old tools and use the `iproute2` toolset.